# Storing default value in Application settings (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, settings

I am using Application settings to store and retrieve my GUI settings. 
For one of the setting

Name - FileDirectory

Type - String

Scope - User

Value - Problem?? i need to store Desktop folder  path i.e Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

I can't set this in Settings Page. 
How can i set this default value?

P.S I am using C# (.Net 2.0)

Comment: You mean the App.exe.config will be used for reading and writing of settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be a check at startup :

```
if(string.IsnullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.FileDirectory))
{
Settings.Default.FileDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Actually i wanted the way to initialize. Anyway it's OK.