# Reset settings to SpecialFolder

Tags: c#, .net, settings, reset

I store the directory path of a folder in Properties.Settings.Default.Temporary and I  allow the user to change this value and other settings using a PropertyGrid.

When the user decides to reset the Settings, I would like to change Properties.Settings.Default.Temporary to the value of System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() by using Properties.Settings.Default.Reset()

I know about System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute. Something like this:

```
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath())]
```

does not work.

I also read [Storing default value in Application settings (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341821/storing-default-value-in-application-settings-c), which described a related problem, but I wonder if there is a way to solve my problem in the way described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had an idea for a workaround myself:

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute(null)]
    public string TemporaryDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            if (this["TemporaryDirectory"] == null)
            {
                return System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
            }
            return ((string)this["TemporaryDirectory"]);
        }
        set
        {
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(value) == false)
            {
                throw new System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException("Directory does not exist.");
            }
            this["TemporaryDirectory"] = value;
        }
    }
```

I don't know, if this has any side effects, but so far it seems to work. I am sorry that I had this idea shortly after posting. I should've thought about the problem a bit longer.

Comment: I accepted my own answer, as it proved to be a viable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The [`DefaultSettingValueAttribute.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.defaultsettingvalueattribute.value.aspx) property is a `string`, therefore you cannot pass a function call to be called when the value is used. In fact there is no ability to pass code to an attribute: only literals are possible.

Instead in your applications code where you reset the settings, follow this by setting and settings that you want to have values that are not literals at compile time (eg. dependent on the execution environment).